# generating dynamic word documents for mass mailing

Tags: php, ms-word

I need to generate a mass mailing based on a word document model with PHP.
Given is a database with the adresses and the data that need to be filled in my word model.
I want to generate a single word document with the different adresses and field contents from the database.

We have a Linux server and the COM object is not avalaible.

Is there a ready to use class to do this? Did you had any experiance with PHPWord?
What is the best practice in this case?

In the ideal case the client should just upload th word master document, with the fields that need to be filled and then fusioned to a multiple pages word document containing the whole mailing.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use Microsoft Word as a model for HTML emails.

Create some HTML templates, then use PHP to iterate through your database and replace certain fields in the HTML.

Comment: It's not for physical mailing, not for e-mails

Comment: Hi I don't understand your comment.  Is it for a snail-mailing?  Or is it for a mass emailing?